# Динамическое изменение страницы при ajax запросе с другого устройства

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

не уверен, что правильно задаю вопрос, пока ламер. Есть JS висящий на странице:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#unban').submit(function () {

        $.ajax({
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            type: $(this).attr('method'),
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "/lobby/ajax/unban_users",
            success: function (response) {
                $("#unbun").trigger('reset');
                var to_unban = response['unbanned'];
                to_unban.forEach(function(item, i, arr){
                    $('#li-ban-'+item).remove();
                });
                
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response['errors']);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
})
```

Запрос идет на url который обрабатывает Django:

```
@login_required
def ajax_unban_user(request) -> JsonResponse:
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():
        to_unban = request.POST.getlist('to_unban')
        lobby_id = int(request.POST.get('lobby_id'))
        _unban_users(to_unban, Lobby.objects.get(id=lobby_id))
        return JsonResponse({'unbanned': to_unban}, status=200)
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'errors': 'Not post or ajax'}, status=400)
```

Вопрос в следующем - как при выполнении и обработке запроса с другой страницы изменить содержимое на всех открытых страницах?
UPADTE
Мне подсказали что то что мне нужно это Webhooks, но я не уверен, как подступиться к этой теме.

Comment: "на всех открытых страницах" - на всех компьютерах мира?

Comment: Предположительно, что везде, где открыта эта страница

Comment: Тогда вам нужны websocket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Действительно, [Stepan Kasyanenko](https://stackexchange.com/users/7741143/stepan-kasyanenkostepan-kasyanenko) подсказал название той технологии, которая мне нужна. Жаль люди которые поставили минус вопросу не объяснили, что я написал не правильно. Но в любом случае вопрос закрываю.

Comment: Не расстраивайтесь, у людей много на что может тригернуть. По вашему вопросу. Вам действительно нужны вебсокеты. Как это будет работать, один из вариантов. У вас на сервере поднят сокет, который принимает запрос на подключение, условно вы вошли в игру, он вам запомнил. Затем он принимает запросы от уже знакомых пользователей(назовем их каналами), как-то обрабатывает и (самое главное) в какой-то момент рассылает по всем своим каналам апдейт.

Comment: Что посмотреть по теме: как на стороне клиента подключиться к вебсокету https://learn.javascript.ru/websockets, как работать с вебсокетами на django https://django.fun/tutorials/django-websockety-i-channels/, полный процесс но там связка django+vue https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hpMnjxyegDM&ab_channel=DjangoSchool однако поймете идею и как в целом реализовать. Удачи